# How to change number of columns in GridView layout

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime

I have Metro app with following layout:

```
 <!-- Horizontal scrolling grid -->
    <GridView 

            x:Name="itemGridView"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsGridView"
            AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
            TabIndex="1"

            Padding="116,136,116,46"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyMenu}}"
            SelectionMode="None"
            IsSwipeEnabled="false"
            IsItemClickEnabled="True"

            ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick" FontSize="12" FontStyle="Italic" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >

      <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
          <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="250" Height="250"  Background="Transparent">

            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}" />

            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="Transparent" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" 
                         Style="{StaticResource GroupHeaderTextStyle}"  Margin="15,0,15,10" FontSize="20" TextAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
          </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
      </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
  </Grid>
```

Thing is that items in this grid are now showing like this:
X X 
X
while I want them to look like this
X X X

Comment: Try removing the Margin of the `TextBlock`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, when I see hard set TabIndex's and crazy Padding's on stuff I immediately think someones got a sloppy layout and an obfuscated DOM, but that's just a comment.

For your question though, you'll just need to go instruct it how you want to layout its children items by specifying the `ItemsPanel` that suits your needs.

So something more like this would be added to it along with your existing `ItemTemplate`;

```
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
   <ItemsPanelTemplate>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
   </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: "TabIndex's and crazy Padding's" was taken from default VisualStudio template.

Comment: but this solution helps

Comment: Ah no worries, never trust the defaults lol, but glad you found your remedy :)